# How did the word "impart" come to be associated with "store"?

Tags: etymology, verbs

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impart) gives the definition of "impart":

> to give, convey, or grant **from or as if from a store**

I've never heard/seen the word described that way before. How is it connected to merchandise from a store?

Etymology-wise:

Merriam Webster:

> Middle English, from Anglo-French & Latin; Anglo-French empartir, from Latin impartire, from in- + partire to divide, part

Lexico:

> late Middle English (in the sense ‘give a share of’): from Old French impartir, from Latin impartire, from in- ‘in’ + pars, part- ‘part’.

[etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/impart):

> early 15c., "to give a part of (one's possessions);" late 15c., "to share, take part in," from Old French empartir, impartir "assign, allot, allocate, share out" (14c.), from Late Latin impartire (also impertire) "to share in, divide with another; communicate," from assimilated form of in- "into, in" (from PIE root *en "in") + partire "to divide, part" (from pars "a part, piece, a share," from PIE root *pere- (2) "to grant, allot").
>
> Meaning "communicate as knowledge or information" is from 1540s; the word was not originally restricted to immaterial things but now usually is only in reference to qualities.

Its Latin origin doesn't seem to have to do with selling, buying, doing business, either. I am curious where Merriam Webster got that definition from.

Comment: Note that a 'store' doesn't have to be a place that sells merchandise, or where business is done, but in US such a place is called a 'store'.

Comment: ... for example "She imparted advice from her store of knowledge."

Comment: @WeatherVane If that were the intended meaning, wouldn't there be better (less ambiguous) phrasing than what's there in M-W?

Comment: Perhaps it's intended to convey that source isn't depleted. She imparts knowledge, but still has just as much.

Comment: Why not try looking up [store in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/store)? "Definition of store 1a: something that is stored or kept for future use"

Comment: There must be a story behind why the word "store" is used to mean a place where things are sold instead of a place where things are stored.

Comment: To *grant as if from a store* does not impart the meaning of selling from a shop. I'd   avoid fixating on one interpretation, then fighting it. When others don't see it that way, it comes across as arguing with a text after distorting it.

Comment: That *is* an awkward definition from M-W. But *store* means, roughly, *stockpile*.

Comment: @Peter I suspect that stores were originally community stockpiles in the days when royals owned everything. Eventually maintenance of these became an occupation, and they turned into businesses that store and sell items.

Comment: What an awful definition.  Look, everybody has their preferred dictionary.  Have you chosen yours yet?

Comment: @aparente001 I absolutely have, and mine _IS_ M-W. That's why I was stumped by this.

Comment: @EddieKal - Okay, if you like it in general then I guess it's a case of *nobody's perfect.*  Did you check any other dictionaries?